# Google Webmaster crewl server error

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

I have setup my website on google webmaster. As i was looking into Crwal errors i was few server errors and URL Errors.

URL Error(404): 
I have a page like this /home/GetCitiesShow which. This page dosent have a physical link on my website, but i use that page as  intermediate page. If i add that URL in address bar, site will display  a custom page not found error which i have created.

This page show up in my google webmaster in URL Error section. 
I have bunch of questions regarding this
1) How google crawled this page? Its dostn have a physical link or a physical page(.html or .asp) on site and its not in sitemap.xml.
2) IF i have maintain a custom page not found on page based on URL request , why its coming up as 404 Error on google webmaster?
3) Best practice for this error? Add it in robot.txt or handle error differently or just do something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many reasons that you are showing 404 error of some page that dones not even exit in you web sites
1. May be your domain was previously in used and already indexed in google
2. You used a theme that creates demo pages and those pages indexed automatically as Google bot always keep searching and indexing new pages in search.
Try search in google **site:yourdomain.com** to explore all indexed page of your domain/website
you can submit request to remove unwanted url through google webmaster/search console

Comment: Thanks @ziab for the comment. i will monitor my webmaster.